# Django: NameError after creating a model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am having a strange error when trying to create model instances for a homepage. I am running a script from the `django` `python` shell containing:

```
def populate_homepage():
    home = HomePage.objects.create(name="Seeker Test")
    navbar_logo = "seeker_theme/img/seekicon.png"
    entry_names = ["Home", "Aboot", "Capabilities", "The Team", "Contact"]
    nav_bar = NavBar.objects.create(name="navbar",
                                    home_page=home,
                                    logo="seeker_theme/img/seeker.png")

    for name in entry_names:
        print(name)
        Entry.objects.create(nav_bar=nav_bar, 
                             primary=False,
                             link="#" + name.lower(),
                             text=name)
```

It appears as though whenever I create a model, such as when I define `nav_bar`, all variables declared in the function scope disappear (`entry_names`, `navbar_logo`), and I get an error.

Is there any strangeness happening behind the scenes in `Django` that would make this happen?  Does `python` leave the scope of `populate_homepage`?  And is there a workaround?

This doesn't happen when I declare variables in a global scope outside of the function, but I would like everything to be contained in the `populate_homepage()` function.

Update: Traceback:

```
C:\Users\Dante\Documents\gains\site>python manage.py shell < mainpage/create_mainpage.py
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 08:04:48) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
In [2]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...: Out[2]: '\nCreated on Thu Oct 11 14:46:41 2018\n\n@author: \n\nNotes: setup is not necessary when running on django shell\n\nUse fixtures: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures\n\nDump Data:\npython manage.py dumpdata --format=json mainpage > mainpage/fixtures/initial_data.json\n\nReset app (clears all data):\npython manage.py migrate mainpage zero\n\nSync with fixtures:\npython manage.py migrgate\n\n\nMust run this file from shell: \n    python manage.py shell < mainpage/create_mainpage.py\n'

In [3]:
In [3]:    ...:    ...:
In [4]:
In [4]:
In [5]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:
In [6]:
In [7]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:
In [8]:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...:    ...: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-5d02778b4a57> in <module>()
----> 1 for name in entry_names:
      2     print(name)
      3     Entry.objects.create(nav_bar=nav_bar,
      4                          primary=False,
      5                          link="#" + name.lower(),

NameError: name 'entry_names' is not defined

In [9]:
In [10]:
In [11]:
In [12]: Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?

C:\Users\redacted\Documents\gains\site>python manage.py reset mainpage
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens.  Edit the question to include the complete error traceback message.

Comment: Are you sure that the forloop runs inside the function? I'm asking just to make sure that you didn't accidentally placed the forloop with one indentation level less, leaving it outside the function.

Comment: Ah, and you probably want to remove the comma after `navbar_logo`, because I don't think you want that variable to be a tuple, just a plain string.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Removed the comma, but I'm still getting the same error.  I've added the traceback message

Comment: And unfortunately, the for loop is definitely inside the function, it is copy-pasted exactly as I posted.

Comment: Ralf is correct here. There are some gotchas to using `<` with a python interpreter, one of which is that two consecutive newlines is treated as the end of an indentation block. A quick fix is to remove the empty line before the for-loop; a better way is to not use < and just run the python file, doing whatever imports/etc you need done that the django shell is doing for you now.

Comment: Oh wow, you're exactly correct!  That is the answer!  I can just remove the newline for now, and that works.  Thanks to the both of you.  Is there an easy way to see what I need to do to replicate the imports of the django shell?  Because I struggled with that for a while and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Probably you can just use a one-off [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) - just put the relevant model imports (for `HomePage`, `NavBar`, `Entry`) at the top, and the current function body in the `handle` method.

Answer (score 0):

So, to close this, Ralf's comment below the question was correct, as confirmed by AdamKG. This is a copy of it:

> Ralf is correct here. There are some gotchas to using < with a python
>   interpreter, one of which is that two consecutive newlines is treated
>   as the end of an indentation block. A quick fix is to remove the empty
>   line before the for-loop; a better way is to not use < and just run
>   the python file, doing whatever imports/etc you need done that the
>   django shell is doing for you now.